# How to connect to MYSQL database in remote server in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, phpmyadmin

As I run my asp.net application in my remote server it shows the following error:

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Source Error: 
Line 15:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 16:       <assemblies>
Line 17:         <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version= 6.6.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
Line 18:         <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 19:       </assemblies>
Source File: D:\Hosting\12557669\html\dev.caribou.in\asp\web.config    Line: 17
Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

*

Comment: Where is the MySql.Data assembly file?  (*Probably* called `MySql.Data.dll` but *might* not be.)

Comment: Double check that `Mysql.Data.Dll` is in the bin folder of your solution on the remote server. Otherwise you have to upload that file to the bin folder.

Comment: actually i tested the application in localhost .how to add dll in remote server

Comment: @user3530708: It *should* be as simple as including the file in the `bin` folder for the application.  When you compile the project, is the file included in the `bin` output?  If not, you may need to change the properties for the `MySql.Data` reference and set it to "copy local".

Comment: i directly added the dlls into my webapplication using addreferances not in bin folder. so how to add in bin